# Write HTML Tag in confirm or alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to achieve something similar to the following

```
confirm ('<h1>Hello</h1>')
```

The expected output should be the Hello in confirm box with h1 element font-size

Comment: You cannot place HTML in a system-level dialog box. To achieve what you need you would need to use a JS library which renders a modal control as part of the webpage using HTML & CSS for content and styling. There are lots available, including [Bootstrap](https://demos.devexpress.com/bootstrap/Layout/Popup.aspx#ModalMode) and [jQueryUI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: If you want this functionality, use a modal

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the alert box because it is a system object. If you need customization, you will need to create your own HTML element.